# im trying to make a monster move randomly from room to room

Tags: python

I'm making a text-based game that occurs in a castle and I want the monster to move randomly between the rooms to make the game over occur at random times I was thinking of using import random and setting each value to 25% but it says local value exits not used I have tried some other systems for movement but it relied on the movement of the player.

```py
rooms = {
    'Entrance Hall': {'name': 'Entrance Hall', 'exits': {'North': 'Great Hall', 'West': 'Bathroom'}},
    'Great Hall': {'name': 'Great Hall', 'exits': {'West': 'Bedroom', 'East': 'Kitchen', 'North': 'Throne Room',
                                                   'South': 'Entance Hall'}},
    'Bedroom': {'name': 'Bedroom', 'exits': {'North': 'Great Hall', 'East': 'Cellar', 'West': 'Bathroom'}},
    'Cellar': {'name': 'Cellar', 'exits': {'West': 'Bedroom', 'North': 'Kitchen'}},
    'Attic': {'name': 'Attice', 'exits': {'South': 'Throne Room'}},
    'Kitchen': {'name': 'Kitchen', 'exits': {'South': 'Celler', 'West': 'Great Hall'}},
    'Bathroom': {'name': 'Bathroom', 'exits': {'East': 'Bedroom', 'North': 'Entarnce Hall'}},
    'Throne Room': {'name': 'Throne Room', 'exits': {'South': 'Great Hall', 'North': 'Attic'}},
}


def monster():
    import random
    monster_current_room = rooms['Attic']
    if monster_current_room not current_room:
        print('The monster is currently in', monster_current_room)
        for exits in rooms:
```

this is what I have so far for the rooms and the monsters movement system and I don't want it to rely on the movement of the player at all.

Comment: pick a random item in the `exits`...

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask] and note that this is *not a discussion forum*. We will not help you *design the requirements of your program* - it is your responsibility to determine the *rules that tell you* when the monster moves and how it chooses a destination. " but it says local value exits not used" Please read https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/359146/ and https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example, and also make sure you understand the difference between actual Python errors and what the IDE tells you.

Comment: " I was thinking of using import random and setting each value to 25%" What do you mean by "each value"? How many "values" do you expect there to be, and why? How do those help you solve the problem? Please try to explain your underlying logic *fully*. "I have tried some other systems for movement but it relied on the movement of the player." What do you mean by "relied on"? If you are trying to make other things happen *while waiting for the user to respond to an `input()` prompt*, then that is a **much** harder problem.

Comment: If you want to practice by making games, it is better if you make games that don't have that kind of requirement *until you are satisfied that you understand the fundamentals*, and then try using something more sophisticated for your program's input and output (perhaps `curses` for fancy terminal output with threading to control timing; or perhaps `tkinter` for a simple GUI). Regardless of what you choose for the next step, though, it really is important that you have a solid foundation.

Comment: Also: `if monster_current_room not current_room:` is not valid syntax. Use `!=` to check whether strings are not equal. Finally: also consider https://gamedev.stackexchange.com for questions specific to designing and programming a game.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
rooms = {
    'Entrance Hall': {'name': 'Entrance Hall', 'exits': {'North': 'Great Hall', 'West': 'Bathroom'}},
    'Great Hall': {'name': 'Great Hall', 'exits': {'West': 'Bedroom', 'East': 'Kitchen', 'North': 'Throne Room',
                                                   'South': 'Entrance Hall'}},
    'Bedroom': {'name': 'Bedroom', 'exits': {'North': 'Great Hall', 'East': 'Cellar', 'West': 'Bathroom'}},
    'Cellar': {'name': 'Cellar', 'exits': {'West': 'Bedroom', 'North': 'Kitchen'}},
    'Attic': {'name': 'Attic', 'exits': {'South': 'Throne Room'}},
    'Kitchen': {'name': 'Kitchen', 'exits': {'South': 'Cellar', 'West': 'Great Hall'}},
    'Bathroom': {'name': 'Bathroom', 'exits': {'East': 'Bedroom', 'North': 'Entrance Hall'}},
    'Throne Room': {'name': 'Throne Room', 'exits': {'South': 'Great Hall', 'North': 'Attic'}},
}

import random
current_room = "Bathroom"
monster_current_room = rooms['Attic']
def monster():
    global monster_current_room
    if monster_current_room["name"] != current_room:
        print('The monster is currently in', monster_current_room["name"])
        exits = list(monster_current_room["exits"].values())
        if random.randint(1, 4) == 4:
          monster_current_room = rooms[random.choice(exits)]
```

Coupla edits to your code I made:

1. You named several of the exits incorrectly so I just fixed the typos
2. I made a variable for the current room
3. I made the monster current room a global variable so it is changed whenever monster is called
4. I made random out of the function as importing it many times throughout the code is in unnecessary.

Comment: Thank you but now I'm getting an unexpected indent error for the if statement and the global value

Answer (score 1):

If you want the monster to appear in a random room every time, you can just pick one at random:

```py
import random
def monster():
    monster_current_room = rooms[random.choice(list(rooms))]
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

If you simply want to select one of the rooms at random. To do that you can use `random.choice()` to randomly select a room; but this function works on lists, while you have a dictionary for your rooms, so you need to use `.keys()` on the dictionary to get a list of the keys:

```
import random
monster_current_room = random.choice(list(rooms.keys()))
```

And if you need the other properties of that room, you can get them from the dictionary.

If, on the other hand, the monster is already in a room and you want to limit the monster to moving randomly to a new room that has exits to the rooms it is previously in:

```
import random
list_of_available_rooms = list(rooms[monster_current_room]['exits'])
monster_current_room = random.choice(list_of_available_rooms)
```

Answer (score 0):

Below I implemented possible `move_monster()` function that you might probably wanted to implement according to your description.

This function with a chance of 25% moves given monster from given room to some other room and prints time of move, direction of move and next room. And with a chance of 75% monster remains in same room. Of course I use [random](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html) module for that, [random.random()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.random) function gives me a dice to roll 25% chance, and function [random.choice()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.choice) allows to randomly choose direction of move and next room.

Afterwards I use this function inside infinite loop to emulate movements of three monsters. Movements are done every 0.5 seconds and printed to console.

[Try it online!](https://replit.com/@moytrage/StackOverflow71178138#main.py)

```py
import time

rooms = {
    'Entrance Hall': {'name': 'Entrance Hall', 'exits': {'North': 'Great Hall', 'West': 'Bathroom'}},
    'Great Hall': {'name': 'Great Hall', 'exits': {'West': 'Bedroom', 'East': 'Kitchen', 'North': 'Throne Room',
                                                   'South': 'Entrance Hall'}},
    'Bedroom': {'name': 'Bedroom', 'exits': {'North': 'Great Hall', 'East': 'Cellar', 'West': 'Bathroom'}},
    'Cellar': {'name': 'Cellar', 'exits': {'West': 'Bedroom', 'North': 'Kitchen'}},
    'Attic': {'name': 'Attice', 'exits': {'South': 'Throne Room'}},
    'Kitchen': {'name': 'Kitchen', 'exits': {'South': 'Cellar', 'West': 'Great Hall'}},
    'Bathroom': {'name': 'Bathroom', 'exits': {'East': 'Bedroom', 'North': 'Entrance Hall'}},
    'Throne Room': {'name': 'Throne Room', 'exits': {'South': 'Great Hall', 'North': 'Attic'}},
}

tb = time.time()

def move_monster(monster_name, current_room):
    import random
    if random.random() >= 0.25:
        return current_room
    next_dir, next_room = random.choice(list(rooms[current_room]['exits'].items()))
    print(f"At {time.time() - tb:>5.01f} sec monster '{monster_name}' moved from room '{current_room}' to '{next_dir}' into room '{next_room}'")
    return next_room
    
monsters = [['Kobold', 'Attic'], ['Dragon', 'Kitchen'], ['Spider', 'Bathroom']]

while True:
    for info in monsters:
        info[1] = move_monster(*info)
    time.sleep(0.5)
```

Output:

```
At   0.0 sec monster 'Kobold' moved from room 'Attic' to 'South' into room 'Throne Room'
At   0.0 sec monster 'Dragon' moved from room 'Kitchen' to 'West' into room 'Great Hall'
At   0.0 sec monster 'Spider' moved from room 'Bathroom' to 'North' into room 'Entrance Hall'
At   0.5 sec monster 'Dragon' moved from room 'Great Hall' to 'West' into room 'Bedroom'
At   0.5 sec monster 'Spider' moved from room 'Entrance Hall' to 'West' into room 'Bathroom'
At   1.5 sec monster 'Kobold' moved from room 'Throne Room' to 'South' into room 'Great Hall'
At   1.5 sec monster 'Dragon' moved from room 'Bedroom' to 'West' into room 'Bathroom'
At   2.0 sec monster 'Dragon' moved from room 'Bathroom' to 'North' into room 'Entrance Hall'
At   2.5 sec monster 'Spider' moved from room 'Bathroom' to 'North' into room 'Entrance Hall'
At   3.0 sec monster 'Kobold' moved from room 'Great Hall' to 'East' into room 'Kitchen'
At   3.6 sec monster 'Kobold' moved from room 'Kitchen' to 'West' into room 'Great Hall'
At   4.1 sec monster 'Spider' moved from room 'Entrance Hall' to 'North' into room 'Great Hall'
At   4.6 sec monster 'Kobold' moved from room 'Great Hall' to 'West' into room 'Bedroom'
At   4.6 sec monster 'Spider' moved from room 'Great Hall' to 'North' into room 'Throne Room'
At   6.6 sec monster 'Kobold' moved from room 'Bedroom' to 'West' into room 'Bathroom'
At   8.1 sec monster 'Dragon' moved from room 'Entrance Hall' to 'North' into room 'Great Hall'
At   8.1 sec monster 'Spider' moved from room 'Throne Room' to 'South' into room 'Great Hall'
At   8.6 sec monster 'Dragon' moved from room 'Great Hall' to 'East' into room 'Kitchen'
At   9.1 sec monster 'Kobold' moved from room 'Bathroom' to 'North' into room 'Entrance Hall'
At   9.2 sec monster 'Dragon' moved from room 'Kitchen' to 'South' into room 'Cellar'
At  10.2 sec monster 'Kobold' moved from room 'Entrance Hall' to 'West' into room 'Bathroom'
At  10.7 sec monster 'Dragon' moved from room 'Cellar' to 'North' into room 'Kitchen'
At  11.2 sec monster 'Spider' moved from room 'Great Hall' to 'South' into room 'Entrance Hall'
At  11.7 sec monster 'Spider' moved from room 'Entrance Hall' to 'West' into room 'Bathroom'
At  13.7 sec monster 'Kobold' moved from room 'Bathroom' to 'East' into room 'Bedroom'
At  14.2 sec monster 'Dragon' moved from room 'Kitchen' to 'West' into room 'Great Hall'
At  14.3 sec monster 'Spider' moved from room 'Bathroom' to 'East' into room 'Bedroom'
At  16.8 sec monster 'Kobold' moved from room 'Bedroom' to 'North' into room 'Great Hall'
At  17.8 sec monster 'Kobold' moved from room 'Great Hall' to 'North' into room 'Throne Room'
At  18.3 sec monster 'Dragon' moved from room 'Great Hall' to 'North' into room 'Throne Room'
At  19.3 sec monster 'Spider' moved from room 'Bedroom' to 'North' into room 'Great Hall'
At  19.8 sec monster 'Dragon' moved from room 'Throne Room' to 'South' into room 'Great Hall'
```

Comment: this would be amazing if I was creating a game with multiple monsters that needed to be killed before collecting items

Comment: Please read [answer], don't try to make these kinds of assumptions about what OP wants, and don't try to do this kind of overall program design. Stack Overflow is for *specific* questions asked as described in [ask] and [fitting within the appropriate scope](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) - it is *not a discussion forum*, and as such, we don't try to figure out the true requirements in the answers - only in the comment section. As the Zen of Python says: `In the face of ambiguity, refuse the temptation to guess.`